# How to replace failed to

Tags: single-word-requests

How to replace **failed to** in the following sentence to make it being more polite.

> State-of-the-art algorithms **failed to** find a compromise between accuracy and efficiency.

I think **failed to** is too strict. Am I right?

Comment: "could not", "did not". Although when it comes to algorithms, it's usually just black or white, so "failed to" seems appropriate.

Comment: I'd likely go with "were unable to" or a variation

Comment: What do you mean by "too strict"? If state-of-the-art algorithms were applied to the problem and still the desired compromise could not be found, then the algorithms failed to find it. I don't see anything  "strict" or "impolite" in saying so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that there is nothing *strict* in this context; however, if you are looking for a euphemistic expression, you could say they *are **imbalanced***.

> State-of-the-art algorithms *are **imbalanced*** between
> accuracy and efficiency.

M-W:

> **[imbalance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imbalance)**
> *noun*
>
> :  lack of balance :  the state of being out of equilibrium or out of
> proportion
>
> - **imbalanced** *adjective*
>
> Her depression is caused by a chemical imbalance in the brain.